# How invoke class method into the async method function

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have one error, When I invoke the handleRenderPage method to the async method i got error :
model.js:83 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.handleRenderPage is not a function

I use MVC to write todo project and in the model class I send the todo list array with handleRenderPage method and I use downloadTask to got the todo list from the server and send it to the view class
this is async function:

```
  downloadTask = async() => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:9090/download';
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    this.tasksList = data;
    console.log(this.tasksList);
    //down is the method 
    this.handleRenderPage(this.tasksList);
  }
```

and I invoked this func outside the class :

```
downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {  
  const model = new Model();
  model.downloadTask();
})
```

when user click download btn app should render todo list from the server

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). (You'll need to use `setTimeout` or something to simulate the ajax, details in the link.)

Comment: Side note: Since you're not doing anything with the promise `downloadTask` returns, you need to ensure that you never allow it to reject its promise. The simple way is to wrap all the code in a `try`/`catch` and handle any errors within the `catch` block.

Comment: Please post the entire code of your `Model` class. Does it have a `handleRenderPage` method?

Comment: yes sure : 
```bindRenderPage = (handleRenderPage) => {
    this.handleRenderPage = handleRenderPage;
    this.filterTasks(this.status);
  };

Answer (score 0):

beacause this.tasklist is undefined and you should invoked it in View and then controler get information in model and send it to Model module